# ExpectedException cause of the cause?

Tags: java, junit, exception, hamcrest, expected-exception

I'm trying to verify that all my exceptions are correct. Because values are wrapped in `CompletableFutures`, the exception thrown is `ExecutionException` with cause being the exception that I would normally check. Quick example:

```
void foo() throws A {
  try {
    bar();
  } catch B b {
    throw new A(b);
  }
}
```

So `foo()` translates exception thrown by `bar()`, and all of that is done inside `CompletableFutures` and `AsyncHandlers` (I won't copy the whole code, it's just for reference)

In my unit tests I'm making `bar()` throw an exception and want to check that it's translated correctly when calling `foo()`:

```
Throwable b = B("bleh");
when(mock.bar()).thenThrow(b);
ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();
thrown.expect(ExecutionException.class);
thrown.expectCause(Matchers.allOf(
                instanceOf(A.class),
                having(on(A.class).getMessage(),
                        CoreMatchers.is("some message here")),
        ));
```

So far so good, but I also want to verify that cause of exception `A` is exception `B` and `having(on(A.class).getCause(), CoreMatchers.is(b))` causes `CodeGenerationException --> StackOverflowError`

TL;DR: How do I get cause of cause of expected exception?

Comment: Maybe this question is what you want (I'm not sure): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871216/junit-possible-to-expect-a-wrapped-exception/20759785#20759785

Comment: @RC. Almost, but I must go one level deeper and get the next cause :)

Comment: You should be able to adapt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6528640/180100

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should try with the simple [hasProperty](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasProperty(java.lang.String,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)) Matcher, in order to isolate the problem:

```
thrown.expectCause(allOf(
                    instanceOf(A.class),
                    hasProperty("message", is("some message here")),
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I use to test only the causal class chain.
References :

- [JUnit: Possible to 'expect' a wrapped exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871216/junit-possible-to-expect-a-wrapped-exception/6528640#6528640)
- https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/03/junit-expectedexception-rule-beyond-basics.html

---

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

public class CausalClassChainTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        expectedException.expect(IOException.class);
        expectedException.expectCause(new CausalClassChainMather(Exception.class, RuntimeException.class));

        throw new IOException(new Exception(new RuntimeException()));
    }

    private static class CausalClassChainMather extends TypeSafeMatcher<Throwable> {

        private final Class<? extends Throwable>[] expectedClasses;
        private List<Class<? extends Throwable>> causualClasses;
        private Matcher<Iterable<? extends Class<? extends Throwable>>> matcher;

        public CausalClassChainMather(Class<? extends Throwable>... classes) {
            this.expectedClasses = classes;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            // copy of MatcherAssert.assertThat()
            description.appendText("")
                    .appendText("\nExpected: ")
                    .appendDescriptionOf(matcher)
                    .appendText("\n     but: ");
            matcher.describeMismatch(causualClasses, description);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(Throwable item) {

            List<Class<? extends Throwable>> causes = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Throwable>>();
            while (item != null) {
                causes.add(item.getClass());
                item = item.getCause();
            }
            causualClasses = Collections.unmodifiableList(causes);

            // ordered test
            matcher = contains(expectedClasses);
            return matcher.matches(causualClasses);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like, to verify the cause of the cause:

```
    thrown.expectCause(allOf(
            isA(org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException.class),
            hasProperty("message", containsString("Error deserializing Avro message for id")),
            hasProperty("cause", allOf(
                    isA(org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException.class),
                    hasProperty("message", containsString("missing required field blabla"))
                    ))
            ));
```