# Spring + lombok + @SneakyThrows

Tags: spring-boot, lombok, cglib

I'm using [@SneakyThrows](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows) [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) feature in my [SpringBoot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) project.
I have problems with this feature when CGLIB proxies implementation
it throws
**java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception,
expected but was<java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException>**.
Can it be fixed somehow ?

---

Providing examples.

There is interface and two implementations.

```java
public interface SneakyThrowsExample {
    void testSneakyThrows();
}
```

---

Simple implementation

```java
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component(value = "simpleSneakyThrowsExample")
public class SimpleSneakyThrowsExample implements SneakyThrowsExample {

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public void testSneakyThrows() {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

---

And **@Transactional** implementations. CGLIB will proxy this implementation.

```java
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component(value = "transactionalSneakyThrowsExample")
public class TransactionalSneakyThrowsExample implements SneakyThrowsExample {

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    @Transactional
    public void testSneakyThrows() {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

---

Create @SpringBootTest test and inject these 2 implementation

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.io.IOException;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DefaultSneakyThrowsExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "transactionalSneakyThrowsExample")
    SneakyThrowsExample transactionalSneakyThrowsExample;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "simpleSneakyThrowsExample")
    SneakyThrowsExample simpleSneakyThrowsExample;

    @Test(expected = IOException.class)
    public void testSneakyThrowsSimple() throws Exception {
        this.simpleSneakyThrowsExample.testSneakyThrows();
    }

    @Test(expected = IOException.class)
    public void testSneakyThrowsTransactional() throws Exception {
        this.transactionalSneakyThrowsExample.testSneakyThrows();
    }
}
```

Test ***testSneakyThrowsTransactional*** fails with error

```java
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<java.io.IOException> but was<java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException>

    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at fine.project.TransactionalSneakyThrowsExample$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$57df642e.testSneakyThrows(<generated>)
    at fine.project.DefaultSneakyThrowsExampleTest.testSneakyThrowsTransactional(DefaultSneakyThrowsExampleTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:19)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at fine.project.TransactionalSneakyThrowsExample.testSneakyThrows(TransactionalSneakyThrowsExample.java:21)
    at fine.project.TransactionalSneakyThrowsExample$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e5429d83.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Very interesting problem indeed. Personally, I only use `@SneakyThrows` to hide impossible exceptions, to I never encountered that. Of course not limited to Lombok.

Answer (score 3):

When you use **@Transactional** then Spring will create a proxy for your bean via AOP proxies - [Spring Framework’s declarative transaction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained)

[UndeclaredThrowableException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/UndeclaredThrowableException.html) cause:

> Thrown by a method invocation on a proxy instance if its invocation handler's invoke method throws a checked exception (a Throwable that is not assignable to RuntimeException or Error) that is not assignable to any of the exception types declared in the throws clause of the method that was invoked on the proxy instance and dispatched to the invocation handler.

Lombock [@SneakyThrows](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows):

> Can be used to sneakily throw checked exceptions without actually declaring this in your method's throws clause

It means that your `TransactionalSneakyThrowsExample.testSneakyThrows()` throws checked exception (that undeclared in the `throws` in method signature) it's illegal behavior when instance wrapped in proxy

In this case you can change expected exception to the `Exception.class`:

```java
    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
        public void testSneakyThrowsTransactional() throws Exception {
            this.transactionalSneakyThrowsExample.testSneakyThrows();
    }
```

or you can use `ExpectedException.expectCause()` to cheack `IOException.class` in your test, take a look at [JUnit expect a wrapped exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20759785/8112217)