# How to assert exceptions in @Async void methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-async

I want to assert an exception that should be thrown within an `@Async` void method.

The following fails, even though I already add a `SyncTaskExecutor` explicit.

*org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected RuntimeException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.*

```
@TestConfiguration
public class SyncTaskExecutorTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public TaskExecutor asyncExecutor() {
        return new SyncTaskExecutor();
    }
}


@SpringBootTest
@Import(SyncTaskExecutorTestConfiguration.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> service.run());
    }   
}

@Service
@Async //also @EnableAsync existing on @Configuration class
public class AsyncService {
    public void run() {
        //of course real world is more complex with multiple sub calls here
        throw new RuntimeException("junit test");
    }
}
```

Comment: It fails exactly with this method. Because a `@Async` void method still executes async in a junit test, even if a `SyncTaskExecutor` is provided. So, I still want to test the exception...

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing the same problem.

bilak's post gave the idea of having my custom `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` declared with a `@Component` annotation.
Then, in my custom implmentation of `AsyncConfigurer` I was injecting my custom `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler`.

In my tests, I used the `@MockBean` annotation on my custom `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler`, so I was able to verify that the `handleUncaughtException` was called with the appropriate exception.

Code sample:

AsyncExceptionHandler

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class AsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable throwable, Method method, Object... objects) {

        log.error("Exception while executing with message: {} ", throwable.getMessage());
        log.error("Exception happen in {} method ", method.getName());
    }
}
```

CustomAsyncConfigurer

```
@Configuration
public class CustomAsyncConfigurer implements AsyncConfigurer {

    final private AsyncExceptionHandler asyncExceptionHandler;

    @Autowired
    public TaskExecutorConfiguration(AsyncExceptionHandler asyncExceptionHandler) {

        this.asyncExceptionHandler = asyncExceptionHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncThread::");
        executor.initialize();

        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        return asyncExceptionHandler;
    }
}
```

My unit test:

```
class FooServiceTest extends FooApplicationTests {

    @MockBean
    private AsyncExceptionHandler asyncExceptionHandler;
    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @Test
    void testCreateEnrollmentBioStoreException() throws Exception {

        fooService.doBar();

        ArgumentCaptor<FooException> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(FooException.class);
        verify(asyncExceptionHandler, times(1)).handleUncaughtException(argumentCaptor.capture(), any(), any());

        FooException exception = argumentCaptor.getValue();
        assertEquals("Foo error message", exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way, but I have a void method that was turned into async, so I didn't want to change the return value just for the tests.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `@Async` method get executed asynchronously by a thread from `asyncExecutor` and it is terminated due to `RuntimeException` which doesn't have any impact on Main thread, the actually `Main-Test` thread competes successfully with the rest of flow once after it trigger the async call. So i will recommend to use the [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) to hold the reference of Async process always even it's required or not and truthfully will help in test cases

```
@Service
@Async 
public class AsyncService {

    public CompletableFuture<Void> run() {
        //of course real world is more complex with multiple sub calls here
         throw new RuntimeException("junit test");
    }
 }
```

So in the test you can wait for `Async` thread to complete assert the cause from [ExecutionException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--), Since the `get` method throws `ExecutionException` if this future completed exceptionally

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(wait);
```

One more note you can refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871216/junit-possible-to-expect-a-wrapped-exception) for asserting wrapped exceptions

Comment: Well but that would require changing application code with a return value **just** for the test with no real world use.

Comment: But i will always prefer the keep child job reference, instead of leaving that alone, because that might work in web application but in normal java world the child thread might terminate as soon as parent thread terminates, But it's just my opinion you can wait for  better answers @membersound

Answer (score 1):

What about using [AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.html) that will be defined for your [AsyncConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncConfigurer.html)?

So basically when you execute your method which throws exception you can verify that exception was handled inside handler? Just an idea, didn't tried this.

Comment: That could be indeed an option.